# Does Json.NET SelectTokens guarantee order?

Tags: json.net, jsonpath

Does Json.NET's `JToken.SelectTokens` method guarantee order?

E.g. given this data:

```
{
    "items": [
        { "name": "foo" },
        { "name": "bar" }
    ]
}
```

Will this expression: `obj.SelectTokens("items..name")` always return `['foo', 'bar']`?

Specifically, I'm interested in expected behaviour for doing this across multiple arrays, like:

```
{
    "items": [
        { "name": "foo" },
        { "name": "bar" }
    ]
}

{
    "values": [
        { "quantity": 9 },
        { "quantity": 42 }
    ]
}
```

Can I use `obj.SelectTokens("items..name")` and `obj.SelectTokens("values..quantity")`to correlate "foo" with 9 and "bar" with 42?

My own tests show it to be the case, but without a deeper understanding of the internals, I can't begin to guess what edge cases I'd need to test for.

I've checked code comments, examined the source code (but not gone very far), looked at documentation [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm), [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) and [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) and for any related issues in the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SelectTokens).

The documentation references [this article](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) for information on JPath, but it makes no explicit indication either. Though its mention of this JPath `$..book[(@.length-1)]` returning "the last book in order", at least *implies* that operations are order-sensitive.

Comment: Apparently not, see [JSON.net: select tokens return “nearest” tokens first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51772089/3744182).

Comment: @dbc The question you linked to is dealing with depth-first vs breadth-first iteration. The example there still iterates in a "top-down" style, just that it's breadth-first instead of depth-first.

Comment: My point is only that order is not guaranteed.  I would have expected results to be returned in document order, as is true with [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm), but apparently not.  No guarantee about order is made.

Comment: @dbc The example you've linked is not evidence for or against a guarantee of order, it's just an example of the results being breadth-first rather than depth-first. If it was sometimes breadth-first and sometimes depth-first, that would be a clear indicator that the order isn't guaranteed.