# JSON.net vs XPATH: How to preserve node order in SelectTokens?

Tags: c#, xpath, json.net

XPath 2 states that the nodes order of a selection should be returned in their order in the document.
It looks this is not the case when you SelectTokens(JSONPath) in JSON.Net

When I process the following document

```
string json = @"
{
  ""Files"": {
    ""dir1"": {
      ""Files"": {
        ""file1.1.txt"": {
         ""size:100""},
        ""file1.2.txt"": {
         ""size:100""}
      }
    },
    ""dir2"": {
      ""Files"": {
        ""file2.1.txt"": {
         ""size:100""},
        ""file2.2.txt"": {
         ""size:100""}
      }
    },
    ""file3.txt"": {
     ""size:100""}
  }
}";
```

The order is the following when using JSON.net SelectTokens("$..files.*")

```
dir1
dir2
file3.txt
 file1.1.txt
 file1.2.txt
 file2.1.txt
 file2.2.txt
```

When I expected the following order (as Xpath //files/*)

```
dir1
 file1.1.txt
 file1.2.txt
dir2
 file2.1.txt
 file2.2.txt
file3.txt
```

How should I write my query so that I get a List in the XPath order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of modifying the Json.Net source code, there is not a way that I can see to directly control what order [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) returns its results.  It appears to be using breadth-first ordering.

Instead of using `SelectTokens()`, you could use a LINQ-to-JSON query with the [`Descendants()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_Extensions_Descendants__1.htm) method.  This will return tokens in depth-first order.  However, you would need to filter out the property names you are not interested in, like "Files" and "size".

```
string json = @"
{
  ""Files"": {
    ""dir1"": {
      ""Files"": {
        ""file1.1.txt"": { ""size"": 100 },
        ""file1.2.txt"": { ""size"": 100 }
      }
    },
    ""dir2"": {
      ""Files"": {
        ""file2.1.txt"": { ""size"": 100 },
        ""file2.2.txt"": { ""size"": 100 }
      }
    },
    ""file3.txt"": { ""size"": 100 }
  }
}";

JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);

var files = jo.Descendants()
              .OfType<JProperty>()
              .Select(p => p.Name)
              .Where(n => n != "Files" && n != "size")
              .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", files));
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yRAev4

---

If you don't like that idea, another possible solution is to use a custom [`IComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) to sort the selected properties back into their original document order after the fact:

```
class JPropertyDocumentOrderComparer : IComparer<JProperty>
{
    public int Compare(JProperty x, JProperty y)
    {
        var xa = GetAncestors(x);
        var ya = GetAncestors(y);
        for (int i = 0; i < xa.Count && i < ya.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(xa[i], ya[i])) 
            {
                return IndexInParent(xa[i]) - IndexInParent(ya[i]);
            }
        }
        return xa.Count - ya.Count;
    }

    private List<JProperty> GetAncestors(JProperty prop)
    {
        return prop.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<JProperty>().Reverse().ToList();
    }

    private int IndexInParent(JProperty prop)
    {
        int i = 0;
        var parent = (JObject)prop.Parent;
        foreach (JProperty p in parent.Properties())
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(p, prop)) return i; 
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Use the comparer like this:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);

var files = jo.SelectTokens("$..Files")
              .OfType<JObject>()
              .SelectMany(j => j.Properties())
              .OrderBy(p => p, new JPropertyDocumentOrderComparer())
              .Select(p => p.Name)
              .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", files));
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xhx7Kk

Comment: This answers my question. But if you extend it a bit, it's rather painfull to have to convert a (complex) JSONPath to (a set of) tests in Linq. Too bad the  SelectTokens(JSONPath) does not return the nodes in document order like XPath

Comment: I added another possible solution using a custom comparer to sort the properties back into document order.  Maybe that would work for you.

Comment: I didn't test -yet- the seond solution but this looks to be exactly what I need. Thank you.